# very large php string magically turns into array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am getting an "Array to string conversion error on PHP";

I am using the "variable" (that should be a string) as the third parameter to str_replace. So in summary (very simplified version of whats going on):

```
$str = "very long string";
str_replace("tag", $some_other_array, $str);
```

$str is throwing the error, and I have been trying to fix it all day, the thing I have tried is:

```
if(is_array($str)) die("its somehow an array");

serialize($str); //inserted this before str_replace call.
```

I have spent all day on it, and no its not something stupid like variables around the wrong way - it is something bizarre. I have even dumped it to a file and its a string.

My hypothesis:

1. The string is too long and php can't deal with it, turns into an array.
2. The $str value in this case is nested and called recursively, the general flow could be explained like this:

--code

```
 //pass by reference

function the_function ($something, &$OFFENDING_VAR, $something_else) { 
  while(preg_match($something, $OFFENDING_VAR)) {

        $OFFENDING_VAR = str_replace($x, y, $OFFENDING_VAR); // this is the error

    }

}
```

So it may be something strange due to str_replace, but that would mean that at some point str_replace would have to return an array.

Please help me work this out, its very confusing and I have wasted a day on it.

---- ORIGINAL FUNCTION CODE -----

```
//This function gets called with multiple different "Target Variables" Target is the subject 
//line, from and body of the email filled with << tags >> so the str_replace function knows 
//where to replace them

function perform_replacements($replacements, &$target, $clean = TRUE,
                              $start_tag = '<<', $end_tag = '>>', $max_substitutions = 5) { 
    # Construct separate tag and replacement value arrays for use in the substitution loop.
    $tags               = array();
    $replacement_values = array();
    foreach ($replacements as $tag_text => $replacement_value) {
        $tags[] = $start_tag . $tag_text . $end_tag;
        $replacement_values[] = $replacement_value;
    }

    # TODO: this badly needs refactoring
    # TODO: auto upgrade <<foo>> to <<foo_html>> if foo_html exists and acting on html template

    # Construct a regular expression for use in scanning for tags.
    $tag_match = '/' . preg_quote($start_tag) . '\w+' . preg_quote($end_tag) . '/'; 

    # Perform the substitution until all valid tags are replaced, or the maximum substitutions
    # limit is reached.
    $substitution_count = 0; 
    while (preg_match ($tag_match, $target) && ($substitution_count++ < $max_substitutions)) {
        $target = serialize($target);
        $temp = str_replace($tags,
                    $replacement_values,
                            $target); //This is the line that is failing.
        unset($target);
        $target = $temp;
    }

    if ($clean) {
        # Clean up any unused search values.
        $target = preg_replace($tag_match, '', $target);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the problem. It is actually valid to pass an array as third argument to `str_replace`, so it should not through an error, even if `$str` *was* an array. Could it be that `$some_other_array` is a nested array, and that's responsible for the error?

Comment: To answer one concern: no, long strings never magically turn into arrays. Never.

Comment: Does it work OK when `$str` is a short string?

Comment: Worth uploading the long string somewhere and adding a link to your question

Comment: Try var_dump on the offending value just before str_replace. What does it say about the data type? What is the size of the variable it reports?

Comment: Yea I have tried many var_dumps - all reports for all variables indicate they are all strings.. All parameters are strings thats the confusing part. There is no "array" to be converted, I need to know why php thinks something is an array

Comment: Why are you passing by reference? which version of php are you running?

Comment: this is an ancient code base, so not actually my code (but somehow my problem)... PHP 5.5.8

Comment: Code logic seems off. Why would we being doing a while loop on preg match, then a str_replace within the loop. The str_replace should be enough to replace all occurrences of $OFFENDING_VAR within $something with a $replacementVar.

Comment: because its part of a 10 year old 1million line code base... this is part of the email system which replaces tags like this: <<name>> with other values like "Martha"... This is just a small part of it

Comment: eh - I came to the wrong place for help.. will remove question...

Comment: Don't get emo. You've had all day to bang on it, we've had 5 minutes. I get what you are saying, you have a template with a number of place holders which must be replaced. As you step through each placeholder, you are replacing the placeholder with the value you want. As @Floris mentioned earlier, did you try running the code with a smaller string? Also, remove the & reference, as PHP >=5.2 (I believe) does that under the hood.

Comment: Also if this is just happening after working for 4 years, what recently changed? Did you upgrade php?

Comment: @FaddishWorm - you didn't come to the wrong place; there are lots of people trying to help you figure this out right now. But we can't immediately reproduce your problem so we are asking questions, trying things. If you don't want help, by all means remove your question. But I think you are giving up too easily.

Comment: What changed is the email itself (its about 4000 lines of HTML) - it used to be about 30 lines of HMTL. I also added some extra things to be replaces following the existing code structure.

Comment: Please - try this with a short version of your string, and show the shortest code that results in the problem. Also - what version of php are you using? It may well be a specific line that is causing the problem - if so, do a binary search in your file (does error occur with first half of lines, or last half; keep cutting the "trouble" string in two, until you know the line that is causing the problem).

Comment: Ok so two things changed, the length and some new "things". When debugging lets remove all distractors. Run a 30 line of html with no new things, should execute no problem (as it has for 4 years). Next add a single new thing, does it run? Cool then try it with 4000 lines of html, does it run? Cool then add all things. If any of the steps fail, thats where you need to focus.

Comment: Lol you know you are in trouble when you see: "# TODO: this badly needs refactoring"

Comment: @MikePurcell - you are exactly right. "go back to a working state, then slowly break it".

Comment: Yea I know --- so glad I resigned from this palce.

Comment: yea I think I will just go home and attack it again next week.... I have 3 weeks left at this place before I travel the world for 2 years so I should probably stop caring so much... thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

How do you know `$str` is the problem and not `$some_other_array`?

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/str_replace):

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value
> from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject. If
> replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for
> the rest of replacement values. If search is an array and replace is a
> string, then this replacement string is used for every value of
> search. **The converse would not make sense, though**.

The second parameter can only be an array if the first one is as well.

Comment: I var_dumped all of them and they are strings... I don't know what it is converting from an array to a string, because nothing should be an array except "$y" in the above example

Comment: if that is true, then `$some_other_array` is an awful name for a string.

Comment: `$replacement_array` still sounds like an array, and not a string.

Comment: you can't search for a string, and replace it with an array, that makes no sense. that's exactly what you're doing here: `str_replace("tag", $some_other_array, $str);`

Comment: it worked for about 4 years, so I don't think its broken - (except I broke it somewhere else and it dies here)

Comment: change it to `$search = array('tag'); str_replace($search, $some_other_array, $str);`

Comment: lol - i know how to use str_replace, there is something more confusing at work here, I will post my original code

Comment: I answered your question based on the code you provided. if the code you provided does not match the code that is giving you problems then no one can give you an accurate answer. your example is broken, and this is how to fix it. simple as that.

Comment: don't ask a question about how to fix your broken code, then turn around and say your code's not broken when you get an answer.

Comment: when you work in a big large monolithic code base you will understand this kind of thing. I am not a noob who can't use str_replace, I have 6 years of PHP experience and I was reaching out to other experts because something bizzare was eluding me.

Comment: well then you posed your question poorly. your example was broken, if you don't see that then 6 years of experience didn't do you much good. the size of a script has absolutely nothing to do with anything.

Comment: don't get stroppy coz u missed out on a few points... its not real currency.

If you can't see past superficiality that comes with summarising a problem then stick to answering basic questions